# Why does redirect to enforce SSL with Nginx fail with some browsers?

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I have a node application, which comes with two server processes. One delivering my app itself, another which provides the API. I use Nginx as a reverse proxy, to make both available via 443 (and 80), and proxy requests to the API from an artificial endpoint.

I have the following setup for an nginx Docker container:

The general configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  5;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And the specific server sections for HTTP and HTTPS:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name mydomain.de;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nodejs_project.log;
  charset utf-8;

  rewrite_log on;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name mydomain.de;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nodejs_project.log;
  charset utf-8;

  rewrite_log on;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/bundle.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/webserver.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://mydomain:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite  ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://mydomain:3030;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

The goal is to automatically redirect all HTTP Requests to HTTPS. This is, what happens when I curl the page:

```
→ curl -IL mydomain.de
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.9.15
Date: Sat, 21 May 2016 12:26:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://mydomain.de/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.9.15
Date: Sat, 21 May 2016 12:26:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 30
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: /steps/1
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.15
Date: Sat, 21 May 2016 12:26:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 39705
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"9b19-576TRcOW5QU6nLaobx28iw"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Which looks good to me. First a 301 from HTTP to HTTPS, then a 302 triggered by the application itself.

This works in most of the Browsers, but a few fail. Especially Firefox on Windows, Chrome on iOS and a few others simply do not do anything, when I try to load: `mydomain.de` or even `http://mydomain.de`.

The certificate is fine. It's not self signed but issued by RapidSSL. The bundle includes the root certificate of the CA, the intermediate certificate as well as my server certificate in that order as per documentation. The browsers that redirect properly do not complain about it. The browsers that fail do not complain about the certificate, when I load my page directly via `https://mydomain.de`.

I have even tried adding:

`add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;
includeSubdomains;
preload";`

to the configuration, but it made it even worse. Can anyone tell me, where my mistake here is?

Comment: Look at the browsers console (i.e. developer tools) for any errors and look at the requests the browsers do and where exactly they stop working (also developer tools).

Comment: Could you try to put 'return 301 https://$host$request_uri' in the redirect and add  'proxy_redirect http:// https://;' in the location block /  ?

Comment: Thx @FromBabylon. At least the browsers I have access to do work. I'll check the rest of the list asap, but obviously it was the addition of these two config lines, that made it work.